# How to pass state and its setter to tanstack table ColumnDef

Tags: reactjs, tanstack

I have a `ColumnDef` like this:

```
export const columns: ColumnDef<Dispute>[] = [
  {
    id: 'select',
    header: ({ table }) => (
      <Checkbox
        checked={table.getIsAllPageRowsSelected()}
        onCheckedChange={(value) => table.toggleAllPageRowsSelected(!!value)}
        aria-label='Select all'
      />
    ),
    cell: ({ row }) => (
      <Checkbox
        checked={row.getIsSelected()}
        onCheckedChange={(value) => row.toggleSelected(!!value)}
        aria-label='Select row'
      />
    ),
    enableSorting: false,
    enableHiding: false,
  },
  {
    id: 'details',
    cell: ({ table }) => {
      return (
        <Button>
          <ArrowLeftFromLine />
        </Button>
      );
    },
  },
...
```

And table like this:

```
export function DataTable<TData, TValue>({
  columns,
  data,
}: DataTableProps<TData, TValue>) {
  const [sorting, setSorting] = React.useState<SortingState>([]);
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = React.useState<ColumnFiltersState>(
    []
  );

  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] =
    React.useState<VisibilityState>({});

  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = React.useState({});

  const [cardOpen, setCardOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,

    state: {
      sorting,
      columnFilters,
      columnVisibility,
      rowSelection,
    },
  });

return ...
```

and t I generate cells like this:

```
                  <TableRow
                    key={row.id}
                    data-state={row.getIsSelected() && 'selected'}
                    className='mat-row'
                  >
                    {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => {
                      return cell.column.id === 'details' ? (
                        <Button onClick={() => setCardOpen(true)}>
                          Expand
                        </Button>
                      ) : (
                        <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                          {flexRender(
                            cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                            cell.getContext()
                          )}
                        </TableCell>
                      );
                    })}
                  </TableRow>
```

The thing is that inside `DataTable` I define  `const [cardOpen, setCardOpen] = React.useState(false);` which I'd like to use to open a card when `Details` cell is clicked. How can I pass that state ad its setter to `ColumnDef`? Now I have an `if` there to generate component inside table but I'd like to keep in inside `ColumnDef`

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

##### Having the state available only for the cell: https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/column-def#meta.

Example on your code:

```js
const columns: ColumnDef<Dispute>[] = [
  {
    id: 'details',
    cell: ({ column }) => {
      return (
        <Button onClick={() => column.columnDef.meta.onOpenCard()}>
          <ArrowLeftFromLine />
        </Button>
      );
    },
    meta: {
       cardOpen,
       onOpenCard: () => setCardOpen(true)
    }
  },
```

##### Having the state available for all the rows: https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/table#meta.

Example on your code:

```js
// Your table definition
const table = useReactTable({
    ...
    meta: {
       cardOpen,
       onOpenCard: () => setCardOpen(true)
    }
});

// Then you can use it in your cell like this 
const columns: ColumnDef<Dispute>[] = [
  {
    id: 'details',
    cell: ({ table }) => {
      return (
        <Button onClick={() => table.options.meta.onOpenCard()}>
          <ArrowLeftFromLine />
        </Button>
      );
    },
  },
```

Be sure to follow the documentation about how to have type-safety with declaration merging.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the columns definition by a function instead an array, just like this:

```
export const columns: ColumnDef<Dispute>[] = ({cardOpen, setCardOpen}) => {
    
  const handleClickDetails = () => {
    setCardOpen(true)
  }
  return [
    {
      id: 'select',
      header: ({ table }) => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={table.getIsAllPageRowsSelected()}
          onCheckedChange={(value) => table.toggleAllPageRowsSelected(!!value)}
          aria-label='Select all'
        />
      ),
      cell: ({ row }) => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={row.getIsSelected()}
          onCheckedChange={(value) => row.toggleSelected(!!value)}
          aria-label='Select row'
        />
      ),
      enableSorting: false,
      enableHiding: false,
    },
    {
      id: 'details',
      cell: ({ table }) => {
        return (
          <Button>
            <ArrowLeftFromLine onClick={() => handleClickDetails()} />
          </Button>
        );
      },
    },
  ...
  
  }
```